# Generate C# code from drawn table

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, ms-word

Right now I am developing C# desktop application for some insurance company. Their reports have a lot of unusual tables with a lot of fields and I have to draw all that tables by using C# drawing class which takes a lot of time.
So I was wondering if there is any tool that can generate C# code for that table after drawing that table using mouse? Or if there is any way I can insert some data in already drawn MS Word table?

Comment: Where come the data for report from? Have you heard about Database? SQL? Than you need MS Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use COM to write in MS-Word tables:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-populate-word-tables-with-document-properties

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Reporting Services is the best Tool for Reports (if you are already at the microsoft side)